# How to use libcurl upload stream data by HTTP/2?

Tags: curl, http2

**DESCRIPTION**

I'm working on a project that use `libcurl` with http/2 to upload stream data.

The workflow is:

data producer --> buffer --> curl --> server.

read_cb setted by `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` will fetch data from the buffer when the sock is ready to send.

1. When the curl fetch data too fast, the buffer may be empty. The empty buffer can cause read_cb to return 0, then I can't use the curl handle to send data anymore.([CURLOPT_READFUNCTION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.html))
2. I use `curl_easy_pause` to prevent read_cb return 0. I just want to pause calling read_cb(Only set CURL_READFUNC_PAUSE), but it seems that the write_cb is paused too, so I can't recv data(can capture data recved by wireshark).

**QUESTION**

What's the solution for stream upload using libcurl?
or any step i get wrong?

Thanks for suggestion.

my example code:

```
size_t read_cb(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nitems, void* userdata) {
    Buffer* buf = (Buffer*)userdata;
    if (buf->empty())
        return CURL_READFUNC_PAUSE;
    ...
}
size_t Buffer::put(const char* data, size_t* len) {
    ...
    curl_easy_pause(easy_, CURL_READFUNC_PAUSE);
    ...
}
```

Comment: i find that when put into buffer, call curl_easy_pause(easy_, CURLPAUSE_SEND_CONT) works.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these three steps:

1. I need to install [`nghttp2` from GitHUB](https://github.com/tatsuhiro-t/nghttp2.git) with

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git g++ make binutils autoconf automake autotools-dev libtool pkg-config \
   zlib1g-dev libcunit1-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev libev-dev libevent-dev libjansson-dev \
   libjemalloc-dev cython python3-dev python-setuptools
   git clone https://github.com/tatsuhiro-t/nghttp2.git
   cd nghttp2
   autoreconf -i
   automake
   autoconf
   ./configure
   make
   sudo maeke install
   ```
2. Upgrade you `curl` version with

   ```
   cd ~
   sudo apt-get build-dep curl

   wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.46.0.tar.bz2
   tar -xvjf curl-7.46.0.tar.bz2
   cd curl-7.46.0
   ./configure --with-nghttp2=/usr/local --with-ssl
   sudo make && make install

   echo '/usr/local/lib' > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf
   ldconfig
   ```
3. Execute the following command

   ```
   cur —version
   ```